# Get rid of redis as backplane when using loadbalancer

Tags: asp.net, iis, redis, signalr, sticky-session

**Given**

we have a site on 2 server on iis . Bevore this we have a loadbalancer. we deliver search results with an existing signalR hubg using redis for windows as backplane.

**Problem**

Now we have some bad issues with redis for windows .

I've found some posts that point out using sticky session would make the use of redis obsolete.

is this right ? When activating sticky sessions would signalR also automatically change its behavior or would I have to configure this?

Any hints are very welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activated sticky sessions
removed signalr scaleout code

works!

**Update Feedback:**

After one month we can say that it worked perfectly and no problems have occured since then